# Setting subfloat caption style

Tags: subfloats

I am using **overleaf** and LuaLaTex as the compiler
I am using subfloat to arrange my images but I want to change the caption style From Fig.5 to Fig.5(a) and Fig.5(b). When I just use subfigure, the setting goes well. but when I use subfloat it won't work. Here are my code. I want to know how to correct this, thank you!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,chains}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\geometry{centering,textwidth=0.887589cm,columnsep=.81cm,left=1.6cm,right=1.6cm,top=1.91cm,bottom=2.54cm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage[]{caption2} 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} 
%\renewcommand{\captionlabeldelim}{.~} 
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{Fig.\arabic{figure}(\alph{subfigure})}

\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@thesubfigure}{\thesubfigure\space}
\renewcommand{\p@subfigure}{} \makeatother
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\centering\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\indent\small\bfseries\hspace{0.4cm}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\newcommand{\upcite}[1]{\textsuperscript{\textsuperscript{\cite{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\tnewroman}{\fontspec{Times New Roman}}
\newcommand{\tabincell}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]
{
  \footnotesize     
  \textbf{Key words --} #1
}
\providecommand{\abstrct}[1]
{
 \footnotesize  
  \textbf{Abstract --} #1
} 


\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
%set font style
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]

\centering
\subfloat{\label{fig:1}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\qquad
\caption{subfloat don't work, i want it to be Fig.1(a)}
\label{fig:cont}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-1cm}
\begin{figure}[H]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat{\label{fig:2}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\caption{subfloat don't work, i want it to be Fig.1(b)}
\label{fig:cont}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \subfigure[subfigure work well\label{a}]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}} \quad
  \subfigure[subfigure work well\label{b}]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
   \caption{}
  \label{f8}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Currently, your code is not compilable since some packages are missing. Pleasa add the required packages.

Comment: Do not use the `subfigure` package. This package is deprecated. You can use the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package instead.

Comment: Please explain why you use `\ContinedFloat` here.

Comment: Hi! I use `\ContiendFloat` or use this subfloat instead of subfigure because there are two subfigures in one of my figures, and when I add this figure, because of the lack of space at the end of the page(my article has two columns), it automatically move the whole figure to the next page, and I want the first subfigure of this figure stay in the previous page, the rest one in the next page. I googled and some suggestions use `\ContiendFloat`

Comment: I've updated my code, I copied all the packages I used, but some of them are not relevant to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following MWE, I have replaced the deprecated `subfigure` package with the `subcaption` package and adapted the use of the `\subfloat` command accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float} 

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} 
 
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}  
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\figurename\thefigure(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[subfloat don't work, i want it to be Fig.1(a)]{\label{fig:1}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[subfloat don't work, i want it to be Fig.1(b)]{\label{fig:2}\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly! I found besides my using of packages, the way I set the caption in subfigure `\caption{subfloat don't work, I want it to be Fig.1(b)}` also caused the problem. Thank you again! Have a nice weekend!